# Chart.js Radial axes: is it possible to use multiple axes on radar chart?

Tags: chart.js

The goal is to build radar chart each axes of which has it's own scale (min and max values). Is it possible to do it via chart.js ? If yes, where documentation about it can be found ?

Comment: Since this is a specific usecase there won't be documentation specifically for building radar charts with multiple axes but all documentation about axes can be found here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/

Comment: @LeeLenalee , thanks. Have you ever faces with such usecases ? In official doc it is mentioned  >" The radar chart supports only a single scale. The options for this scale are defined in the scale property. The options for this scale are defined in the scale property, which can be referenced from the Linear Radial Axis page."  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/charts/radar.html

Comment: No also you are looking at outdated documentation, the scale property has been removed, everything is defined in the scales property

Comment: @LeeLenalee , thankx! And what about https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html axes extendindg? Is it possible to register own extended scales excepting default 'x', 'y' and 'r'.  Something like :
        scales: {
            r1: {
                type: 'myScale1' /
            },             r2: {
                type: 'myScale2' 
            },
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround: use Apache eCharts lib. https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=radar
Here is an example with different scale range for each axis in Radar Chart.

[Here is code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiWhz.png)